# Jsoup unexpected exception, was working and suddenly stopped

Tags: java, parsing, exception, authentication, jsoup

My problem is that I wrote a program that login to the website and download the desired data. Everything was fine, the program worked when suddenly stopped working. In the code, there was no change, even though the program began to throw an exception every time. What could cause this? How do I fix this?

The exception is:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at gui.JsoupClass.checkLogin(JsoupClass.java:55)
    at gui.JsoupClass.<init>(JsoupClass.java:31)
    at gui.JsoupClass.main(JsoupClass.java:22)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)`

Here is my code, maybe i dont see something that some1 of you will see:

```
package gui;

import dao.*;
import org.jsoup.Connection;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.SocketTimeoutException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class JsoupClass
{
    static String value[] = new String[3];
    static String name[] = new String[3];

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new JsoupClass("email@gmail.com", "yourpassword", null);
    }

    public JsoupClass(String emailText, String passText, MainFrame mainFrame) {
        Connection.Response res;

        res = getLoginData();
        res = doLogin(res, emailText, passText);

        if (checkLogin(res).hasText()) {
            setUpTrafficPayment(res);
            setUpEwalletData(res);
            setUpPanelsData(res);
            setUpPaymentData(res);
            try {
                if (mainFrame != null)
                    mainFrame.dispose();
                new StatisticFrame();
            } catch (ParseException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(RunFrame.getInstance(),
                    "Wrong Login Data!",
                    "Warning",
                    JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        }
    }

    public Elements checkLogin(Connection.Response res) {
        Document doc = null;
        Elements elements;
        try {
            doc = res.parse();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        elements = doc.select("div#topuserinfo > a > span");
        if (elements.hasText()) {
            UserData userData = UserData.getInstance();
            userData.setNameValue(elements.text());
        }
        return elements;
    }

    public Document getPage(Connection.Response res, String pageAddres) {
        Document doc = null;
        try {
            doc = Jsoup
                    .connect(pageAddres)
                    .cookie("PHPSESSID", res.cookie("PHPSESSID"))
                    .get();
        } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(RunFrame.getInstance(),
                    "Read timed out! Could not open connection to Banners Broker!",
                    "Error",
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return doc;
    }

    public Connection.Response doLogin(Connection.Response res, String email, String pass) {
        Connection.Response res2 = null;
        try {
            res2 = Jsoup
                    .connect("https://bannersbroker.com//user/login?event=doLogin")
                    .cookies(res.cookies())
                    .data("email", email)
                    .data("pass", pass)
                    .data(name[0], value[0])
                    .data(name[1], value[1])
                    .data(name[2], value[2])
                    .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                    .execute();

        } catch (IOException ioe) {
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ioe) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(RunFrame.getInstance(),
                    "Could not open connection to Banners Broker!",
                    "Error",
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        } catch (NullPointerException ioe) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(RunFrame.getInstance(),
                    "Could not open connection to Banners Broker!",
                    "Error",
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
        return res2;
    }

    public Connection.Response getLoginData() {
        Connection.Response res = null;
        try {
            String html;
            int length, counter;

            res = Jsoup
                    .connect("https://bannersbroker.com//user/login?event=doLogin")
                    .execute();

            html = res.parse().toString();
            length = html.length();
            counter = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                if (html.startsWith("document.write", i)) {
                    name[counter] = html.substring(i + 41, i + 144);
                    value[counter] = "Login";
                    counter++;
                }
                if (html.startsWith("hidden", i)) {
                    name[counter] = html.substring(i + 13, i + 81);
                    value[counter] = html.substring(i + 90, i + 123);
                    counter++;
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException ioe) {
        } catch (NullPointerException ioe) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(RunFrame.getInstance(),
                    "Could not open connection to Banners Broker!",
                    "Error",
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
        return res;
    }

    public void setUpEwalletData(Connection.Response res) {
        Document doc;
        Elements elements;
        doc = getPage(res, "http://bannersbroker.com/adpubcombo_ewallet/ewallet");
        elements = doc.select("p[class=ewallet_numbers");
        EwalletData ewalletData = EwalletData.getInstance();
        ewalletData.setWalletValue(Double.parseDouble(elements.first().text().replaceAll("[\\D&&[^.]&&[^-]]+", "")));
    }

    public void setUpPanelsData(Connection.Response res) {
        MacroData macroData = MacroData.getInstance();
        TrafficData trafficData = TrafficData.getInstance();
        PanelsData panelsData = PanelsData.getInstance();
        String strona;
        Document doc;
        Elements elements;
        int[] traffic = new int[8];
        int[] macro = new int[7];

        for (int i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
            strona = "http://bannersbroker.com/adpubcombo_manageinventory/viewactivepanels?colour=" + i + "&sort=Qualified";
            doc = getPage(res, strona);

            elements = doc.select("span[id=limit2]");
            macro[i - 1] = Integer.parseInt((elements.first().text().replaceAll("\\D+", "")));

            elements = doc.select("div.number[id=js-tp-bank]");
            traffic[i - 1] = Integer.parseInt((elements.first().text().replaceAll("\\D+", "")));

            elements = doc.select("p[id^=QualDate]");
            if (elements.hasText()) {
                String[] luzem = elements.text().split("[\\D&&[^-]]+");
                Date[] aray = new Date[luzem.length / 4];
                try {
                    int j = 0;
                    while (elements.eq(j).hasText()) {
                        if (elements.eq(j).text() != "")
                            aray[j] = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss").parse(elements.eq(j).text());
                        j++;
                    }
                    j = 0;
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                switch (i) {
                    case 1:
                        panelsData.setYellowDays(aray);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        panelsData.setPurpleDays(aray);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        panelsData.setBlueDays(aray);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        panelsData.setGreenDays(aray);
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        panelsData.setRedDays(aray);
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        panelsData.setBlackDays(aray);
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        panelsData.setPrestigeDays(aray);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }

            elements = getPanelData(doc);
            if (elements.hasText()) {
                int size = getPanelData(doc).size();
                for (int j = 1; j <= size / 2; j++) elements.remove(j);
                String[] luzem = elements.text().split("[\\D&&[^.]]+");
                Double[] aray = new Double[luzem.length];
                for (int j = 0; j < luzem.length; j++)
                    aray[j] = Double.parseDouble(luzem[j]);

                switch (i) {
                    case 1:
                        panelsData.setYellow(aray);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        panelsData.setPurple(aray);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        panelsData.setBlue(aray);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        panelsData.setGreen(aray);
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        panelsData.setRed(aray);
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        panelsData.setBlack(aray);
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        panelsData.setPrestige(aray);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        doc = getPage(res, "http://bannersbroker.com/adpubcombo_trafficbank/managetraffic");
        elements = doc.select("h4[id=trafficLeft_4]");
        if (elements.first() != null)
            traffic[7] = Integer.parseInt((elements.first().text().replaceAll("[\\D+]", "")));

        trafficData.setTraffic(traffic);
        macroData.setMacro(macro);
    }

    public static Elements getPanelData(Document doc) {
        Elements elements = doc.select("span.cost");
        return elements;
    }

    public void setUpPaymentData(Connection.Response res) {
        Document doc;
        Elements elements;
        doc = getPage(res, "http://bannersbroker.com/adpubcombo_manageinventory/viewpackagespurchased");
        elements = doc.select("tr > td[align=center][valign=middle] > div");
        try {
            PaymentData.getInstance().setAbonamentDate(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(elements.last().text()));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void setUpTrafficPayment(Connection.Response res) {
        Document doc;
        Elements elements;
        doc = getPage(res, "https://bannersbroker.com/adpubcombo_account/account");
        elements = doc.select("div[class=infogroup] > div[class=tablecont] > table > tbody > tr > td[align=center]:not(td[class])");
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) elements.remove(0);
        int length = elements.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < length / 3; i++) {
            elements.remove(i);
            elements.remove(i);
        }
        PaymentData.getInstance().setTpAmount(elements.size());
        Date[] array = new Date[elements.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < elements.size(); i++)
            try {
                array[i] = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(elements.eq(i).text());
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        PaymentData.getInstance().setTpDate(array);
    }
}
```

The constructor get email, password and frame, frame in this case is not important so i send from main method null, it get frame when i want to send email and password from frame but every time when i debug is no convenient to do that so skipping the login window.

```
public JsoupClass(String emailText, String passText, MainFrame mainFrame) {
        Connection.Response res;

        res = getLoginData();
        res = doLogin(res, emailText, passText);

        if (checkLogin(res).hasText()) {
            setUpTrafficPayment(res);
            setUpEwalletData(res);
            setUpPanelsData(res);
            setUpPaymentData(res);
            try {
                if (mainFrame != null)
                    mainFrame.dispose();
                new StatisticFrame();
            } catch (ParseException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(RunFrame.getInstance(),
                    "Wrong Login Data!",
                    "Warning",
                    JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
```

`getLoginData()` method parse cookies and some hidden fields needed to login
`doLogin(res, emailText, passText)` use the data got from `getLoginData()`, our email and password to log us in. Next step is `if (checkLogin(res).hasText())`, `checkLogin(res)` return elements so if `elements.hasText` we know that we logged in succesfull, else not.
Then when we are logged in i parse needed data to mine classes witch methods:

```
            setUpTrafficPayment(res);
            setUpEwalletData(res);
            setUpPanelsData(res);
            setUpPaymentData(res);
```

And as i said at begining all was working, and suddenly it start to throw an exception every time.

Banners Broker is a private marketplace, signups are by referral only at this time.
If enyone want to creat an account and try to login heres a link to sign up.
https://bannersbroker.com/vardius

Comment: @baraky helped me a lot, code is good the server got problems that's why it isnt working atm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you call `checkLogin(null)`.
You can make sure `res = doLogin(res, emailText, passText);` isn't null before calling `checkLogin`.

Try using:

```
if (res != null && checkLogin(res).hasText()) {
```

Its bad practice to catch exception (`IOException` in your case) and do nothing (at `doLogin` and `getLoginData`). You can either throw the exception or add log, but ignoring it may hurt you in another place. That's exactly what happened here...

Change this code:

```
} catch (IOException ioe) {
} catch (IllegalArgumentException ioe) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(RunFrame.getInstance(),
            "Could not open connection to Banners Broker!",
            "Error",
            JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
```

To this:

```
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        // Here print the ioe stack trace to whenever you want and check why you get this exception.

    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ioe) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(RunFrame.getInstance(),
                "Could not open connection to Banners Broker!",
                "Error",
                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
```

Comment: so why `doLogin(res, emailText, passText);` return null ? i havent change nothing it was working and suddenly stoped. what could be a reason ? maybe website change smth?

Comment: You can add logging inside your catch (IOException ioe) both in doLogin and in getLoginData. This will help you understand the error.

Comment: you mean i should do 
            `res2 = Jsoup
                    .connect("https://bannersbroker.com//user/login?event=doLogin")
                    .cookies(res.cookies())
                    .data("email", email)
                    .data("pass", pass)
                    .data(name[0], value[0])
                    .data(name[1], value[1])
                    .data(name[2], value[2])
                    .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                    .execute();`
in `catch (IOException ioe){` here `}` of `doLogin` method ?

Comment: yep. And in getLoginData also at the same place.

Comment: ok so i did, at both methods and it allways get null logging in `catch (IOException ioe)` of `getLoginData`. But i still dont get it why it doesnt want to login and return null. before it was working and from yesterday it stoped.

Comment: What does the exception says? Not the NPE one, the IOException.

Comment: it says nothing
i had to serround with try catch the logging also in `catch (IOException ioe)`

and exception inside cath return null no other exceptions

Comment: I've edited my answer. Change the catch clause the print the IOE stack trace.

Comment: so i did in both methods `doLogin` and `getLoginData` `catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }` and the exception is: `java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out`

Comment: So now you know what you need to solve. Looks like the server doesn't response.

Comment: any ideas how to make him to response ?

Comment: Where is the server? you can try and connect it using other device (browser/wfetch)

Comment: https://bannersbroker.com/
it doesnt load now but it does before and i wasn't able to login.

Comment: So the error is the server. Check why it doesn't load now. Maybe you need to republish. Don't really know bannersbroker.com

Comment: republish? i know what that word mean but i don't understand what to republish ? and what is the meaning of this action.

Comment: If the server isn't yours, you need to check what is the problem with the server. I don't know how to help you more...

Comment: ok, at least we got to smth. now the question is how to check what is the problem with that server.